# json encoding error on joomla page (RokSprocket plugin)

Tags: ajax, json, joomla

So i have a RokSprocket joomla plugin where I load all the joomla articles from table, the problem is that i have around 80 articles, and on load i show only 10 of them and a button to load more. 2nd time when i click on the button new 10 articles are loaded, after that when i want to click 3rd time, i cant load them, I get an error like this:

```
{"status":"error",
"message":"UNHANDLED ERROR [2] json_encode() [function.json-encode<\/a>]:
Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument \/joomla\/libraries\/rokcommon\/RokCommon
\/Ajax.php:93","payload":null}
```

And in the line 93 of that file (Ajax.php) I have

```
$encoded_result = json_encode($result);
```

I don't know where is the error really, how can I load 2 times 20 articles OK, and than when i click 3rd time I get an error and nothing loaded.

This is also shown in the Firebug console:

```
Error: RokSprocket Error [model: 
mosaic, model_action: getPage, 
params: {"moduleid":"706","behavior":"append","displayed":[382,400,401,402,403,404,405,406,407,408,409,410,411,412,413,414,415,416],"filter":"all",
"page":3}]: 
UNHANDLED ERROR [2] json_encode() [<a href='function.json-encode'>function.json-encode</a>]: Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument /joomla/libraries/rokcommon/RokCommon/Ajax.php:93
...querySelector;}finally{if(!y){if(C){x.setAttribute("id",C);}else{x.removeAttribu...
```

Any help would be appreciated since everything I searched and tried didn't gave me positive results.

Comment: Perhaps you have some characters in the description of the article which break the json function. Try to simplify it. That's how I would start chasing it.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$result` appears to be in a wrong encoding: `json_encode` expects strings to be encoded in UTF-8: [see the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

First dump the variable to see what type it has (it's not necessarily a string) then convert it as appropriate (you could use `mb_convert_encoding`)

Answer (score 0):

You have to check all modified RockSprocket language ini files.
All ini files need to be saved as UTF-8.